# Interpretation of Postgres Actual Loops in EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql

When reading a Postgres `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan, the documentation [states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-ANALYZE) that under *some* conditions, operators may be executed more than once (as indicated by `Actual Loops`). In these cases, some performance measurements are shown as per-loop, rather than aggregated for the entire operator (e.g. `Actual Total Time` and `Actual Rows`):

> In some query plans, it is possible for a subplan node to be executed more than once. For example, the inner index scan will be executed once per outer row in the above nested-loop plan. In such cases, the loops value reports the total number of executions of the node, and the actual time and rows values shown are averages per-execution. This is done to make the numbers comparable with the way that the cost estimates are shown. Multiply by the loops value to get the total time actually spent in the node. In the above example, we spent a total of 0.220 milliseconds executing the index scans on tenk2.

However, I found multiple instances of query plans where the `Actual Total Time` of a sub-node becomes larger than the total time of the root node, when multiplied by the number of loops. It seems like in these cases, the total time reflects the actual total time, rather than the per-loop average (example below).

**So, under which conditions is it necessary to multiply the values of `Actual Rows` and `Actual Total Time` by `Actual Loops` in order to get the correct results, and under which conditions are the values already aggregated correctly?**

### Example:

The query `explain analyze select count(*) from name n join person_info pi on n.id = pi.person_id;`

produces the following plan:

```
    QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=233201.06..233201.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1770.430..1823.586 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=233200.84..233201.05 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=1769.845..1823.580 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=232200.84..232200.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1768.782..1768.813 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=145078.16..227887.97 rows=1725150 width=0) (actual time=1234.256..1611.255 rows=1376736 loops=3)
                     Hash Cond: (pi.person_id = n.id)
                     ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using person_id_person_info on person_info pi  (cost=0.43..78281.72 rows=1725150 width=4) (actual time=0.086..195.010 rows=1376736 loops=3)
                           Heap Fetches: 0
                     ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=111851.77..111851.77 rows=2658077 width=4) (actual time=782.084..782.085 rows=2126580 loops=3)
                           Buckets: 131072  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 3040kB
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on name n  (cost=0.00..111851.77 rows=2658077 width=4) (actual time=0.018..345.728 rows=2126580 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.133 ms
 Execution Time: 1823.752 ms
(14 rows)
```

The final aggregate has a total runtime of `1823.586 ms`. However, the last Parallel Hash operation has a runtime of `782.085 ms` with 3 loops. According to the documentation this would lead to a runtime of `782.085 * 3 ms = 2346.255 ms` which is larger than the total runtime of the root node. Since timings always include their children as well, this cannot be.

Comment: There are two workers.

Comment: @Mike Organek : I am unsure how the parallel workers relate to my question. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to give an exhaustive answer, but the rule of thumb is as follows:

- the following only applies to nodes *below* `Gather`, as those are parallelized
- row counts, "rows removed by filter", heap fetches and similar *counts* are divided by the number of processes ("loops"), so you have to multiply them to get the total
- execution times and buffer counts are *not* divided

For the times, this is obvious: if three parallel processes work for a second to compute a result, it only takes one second until they are done, not three seconds. That's the whole point of parallel query!

Comment: Ah, so multiple loops coincide with multiple workers operating in parallel? If that is the case, multiplying the loops with the total time would therefore (roughly) determine how long the node took, if it would have been executed sequentially (which obviously could exceed the total runtime of the parallel query and which apparently is what the documentation is talking about)?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Alright, thank you! This explanation was really helpful!